# File path with write.zoo

Tags: r

I'm using r on Mac OSX and following this guide to download and maintain a collection of CSVs with stock prices.

http://www.thertrader.com/2015/12/13/maintaining-a-database-of-price-files-in-r/

```
library(quantmod)

startDate = "2000-01-01"
thePath = ""

source(paste("listOfInstruments.R",sep=""))

for (ii in theInstruments){
 print(ii)
 data = getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                   src = "yahoo", 
                   from = startDate, 
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
 colnames(data) = c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
 write.zoo(data,paste(thePath,ii,".csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
}
```

I'm trying to keep my R files separately from my CSV files, so I change the variable "thePath" to an existing subdirectory named csv. e.g. `thePath = "\\csv\\"`

However this creates a file which is actually named `\csv\^GSPC.csv` as opposed to writing into a subfolder.

What is the correct way to specify the write.zoo path?

Comment: Did you try `thePath = 'csv/'?

Comment: Try thePath ="~/csv/"